# How to Allow outside touch for BottomSheetDialog?

Tags: android, fragment, bottom-sheet

I am working on `BottomSheetDialogFragment` my requirement is to create Bottom menu,
Where if I *click outside fragment area* it should **not cancel** the Dialog and should persist.

ISSUE: 
**And Event outside the Fragment should propagate to the lower fragment view/fragment.**

I have already tried below(doesn't work for BottomDialogFragment):
[Allow outside touch for DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382540/allow-outside-touch-for-dialogfragment)

To stop the dialog cancel i tried Below(i call `setCancelable(boolean)` in `onStart()` of BottomDialogFragment):

```
@Override
    public void setCancelable(boolean cancelable) {
        super.setCancelable(cancelable);

        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) getDialog();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(cancelable);

        View bottomSheetView = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView).setHideable(cancelable);
    }
```

[reference](https://github.com/andor201995/android-lockable-bottom-sheet/blob/master/lockable-bottom-sheet/src/main/java/net/kyouko/lockablebottomsheet/LockableBottomSheetDialogFragment.java)

EDIT: Found it the hard way there is no other go then using Coordinate layout.The best solution for BottomSheetDialog is [here](https://github.com/andor201995/android-lockable-bottom-sheet/tree/update)

- [This](https://github.com/andor201995/android-lockable-bottom-sheet/tree/update) Solution solve's the issue but bring's in one more issue. i.e all the actionMode event's are not navigated while all other app event's are.
- And this is my best [solution](https://github.com/andor201995/PersistIt) to the problem

Comment: Does [this link][1] help you ? 


  [1]: https://medium.com/@betakuang/make-your-bottomsheetdialog-noncancelable-e50a070cdf07

Comment: @StavroXhardha 

I have already tried this it allow's me to stop the cancel of Dialog but the event's are also blocked for below View's.

Comment: I did found the solution and applied in this demo project https://github.com/andor201995/PersistIt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior`.

but if you want to have a `bottomSheet` in other class I suggest you use a `Fragment` and in this `fragment` open your `bottomSheet`

open your fragment [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36100397/4519936).

And in your fragment, open your `bottomSheet` in the following code:

in `onInitViews`

```
var mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetCoordinatorLayout)
mBottomSheetBehavior!!.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN

mBottomSheetBehavior!!.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
     override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
          when (newState) {
             BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> {
                  fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
             }
             //BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> "Collapsed"
             //BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> "Dragging..."
             //BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> "Expanded"
             //BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> "Settling..."
           }
      }

      override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
          //text_view_state!!.text = "Sliding..."
      }
})
```

And your `layout` should be like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="55dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/top_radius_primary_color"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/material_size_32"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/material_size_32">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: https://github.com/andor201995/PersistIt
it has  some other challenge's if you are using navigation component's.I can't use fragment transaction's.Try this demo project for further enhancement. But the scope of this question this is correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try **code below** in your `BottomSheetDialog`:

```kotlin
 override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
     return (super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog).apply {
         setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
     }
 }
```

or wrap by `<CoordinatorLayout>`  for instance your `<ConstraintLayout>` and implement `<layout />` and attach to `BottomSheetBehavior`.

Comment: Hello i tried this but when i click outside the View then the Dialog is not getting canceled but at same time all the event's are blocked which i want for lower VIew.

I want to know a way to get event's to lower VIew.

Thank's for your reply.

Comment: try to use not a dialog. just include `<layout />` and attach to `BottomSheetBehavior`, it will work fine.

Comment: For that i think i fill be forced to use coordinate layout as root so as to add BottomSheetBehavior as layout_behaviour.But i was just trying to figure out if i can use dialog and bypass the outside touch region.

Comment: hmm, try to turn off `dim` and apply in `styles` some attributes. Maybe will be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227126/how-can-i-change-default-black-dim-background-color-not-the-amount-of-dim-of)

Comment: I think you just need to wrap by `<CoordinatorLayout>`  for instance your `<ConstraintLayout>` and implement `<layout />` and attach to `BottomSheetBehavior`.

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko thanks for your suggestion, it works exactly what I want. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As been said by Pankaj Kumar, this is not possible by default. However, I found a workaround that works and allows touches to views outside of the bottom sheet while keeping the bottom sheet open

You can override the layout of the `BottomSheetDialog` like so:

**values/refs.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item name="design_bottom_sheet_dialog" type="layout" tools:override="true">@layout/custom_design_bottom_sheet_dialog</item>
</resources>
```

**layout/custom_design_bottom_sheet_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ~ This is an override of the design_bottom_sheet_dialog from material library
-->
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      android:id="@+id/coordinator"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/touch_outside"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
        style="?attr/bottomSheetStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"/>

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**YourCustomBottomSheetDialogFragment**

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        // Set layout for custom bottom sheet by allowing background touches
        dialog?.window?.apply {
            setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)
            
            attributes = attributes.apply {
                gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
            }
            setDimAmount(0.0f)
        }
    }
```

By doing this, the dialog has a `wrap_content` height and the flags allow touches to be handled by views outside of this dialog

Comment: Finally! Something clean and easy to use. This worked perfectly for me, I'm so happy that I can kiss you :D! Thank you!!

Comment: Great, but it affects all bottom sheet dialogs. Any way to make this change only for one specific bottom sheet?

Comment: @shko,  I meet this question now ,can you slove this?

Comment: Any solutions for @shko question? Something that works for one specific bottom sheet? Same issue here.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible till you are using `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is a dialog and as behaviour of every dialog, it does not allow user interception on any view behind the dialog, although that is visible to user.

So to achieve this you need to use `Fragment` instead of `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. And yes it will require lot of code changes :) and you have to live without `BottomSheetDialogFragment` if you want to intercept views behind.

Comment: Major issue is (using Fragment) is that my app/Activity is not using `Adjust resize` but according to requirement bottom menu should move up if keyboard is displayed (Example).BottomSheetDialog is itself Intelligent to adjust according to the system resize call's.I am not able to implement same behavior in MyCustomFragment.So i am leaned to use BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: I think if this is only task left then that is doable. You just need to design container layout as like to handle keyboard appears. you can look at https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/move-layout-when-keyboard-shown/ or similar threads

Answer (score 1):

Achieve this implementation with the persistence bottom sheet.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val btnClickOutside: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnClickOutside)
    val btnExpandBottomSheet: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_expand_bottom_sheet)
    val btnCollapseBottomSheet: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_collapse_bottom_sheet)
    val changingState: TextView = findViewById(R.id.changing_state)
    val bottomSheet: View = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet)
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
    
    btnClickOutside.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click working in outside of bottom sheet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    btnExpandBottomSheet.setOnClickListener {
        (bottomSheetBehavior as BottomSheetBehavior<*>).setState(
            BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        )
    }

    btnCollapseBottomSheet.setOnClickListener {
        (bottomSheetBehavior as BottomSheetBehavior<*>).setState(
            BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        )
    }

    (bottomSheetBehavior as BottomSheetBehavior<*>).setBottomSheetCallback(object :
        BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            when (newState) {
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> changingState.text = "Collapsed"
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> changingState.text = "Dragging..."
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> changingState.text = "Expanded"
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> changingState.text = "Hidden"
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> changingState.text = "Settling..."
            }
        }
        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
    })

}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClickOutside"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="OutSide Click"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_expand_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Expand"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_collapse_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Collapse"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/changing_state"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Changing State appear here"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_dialog" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bottom_sheet_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dp"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chicken Fried Rice 1x1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Paneer Tikka 1x2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Delivery Address"
    android:textColor="#444"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="N7, Cidco, Aurangabad - 431001" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The solution is easy and simple. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above,we can not directly use BottomSheetDialogFragment or BottomSheetDialog achieve the effect of allowing touch outside.

But we can realize it with the help of **Dialog and BottomSheetCallback in the BottomSheetDialogFragment**. (Talk is cheap,show you the code)

```kotlin
class BottomPanelFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

 override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    
      val dialog = Dialog(requireActivity(), R.style.ChargeMapDialog)
        val view = requireActivity().layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_around_charge_station_info,
            null
        )
        dialog.setContentView(view)

        dialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
        dialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH)


        dialog.window?.setDimAmount(0F)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

  }   

   override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Set layout for custom bottom sheet by allowing background touches
        dialog?.window?.apply {
            setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)

            attributes = attributes.apply {
                gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
            }
            setDimAmount(0.0f)
        }
    }    
}
```

Corresponding the xml file:

```xml
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // notes：app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/fill_100"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/dp_80"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_charge_station"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_24"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_charge_station_flag"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_charge_station_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_24"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
            android:text="Welcome driving the Tesla model-S"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_400"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_charge_station" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_select_area"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_24"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Los Angeles"
            android:textColor="@color/text_700"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_charge_station"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_select_charge_operator"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_charge_station" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_select_charge_operator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_24"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="select"
            android:textColor="@color/text_700"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_charge_station"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_charge_station" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_charge_station"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dp_24"
            android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dp_20"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_charge_station_info"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:itemCount="3"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_charge_station" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the style.xml

```xml
 <style name="ChargeMapDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/color_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    </style>
```